# MySQL not accepting connections from WP

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, iis-7.5, wordpress, connection

I have a few servers running WordPress. I am using IIS with MySQL. One keeps faulting; I reset the MySQL server and it works well for a few hours and after that I start getting "Error establishing a database connection".

The MySQL is up and I can log in to it as root or regular user, locally or remotely. I see nothing special in `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`, but the aborted connections do increase.

I'm running on a Win2008R2; my other servers are MUCH busier - the one that is not working is my QA server. I copied the my.ini configuration from the working servers to make sure this server can handle as many connections (initially it was set much lower as it is not production; in the installation I also chose DEV server and not production server), but it doesn't help. Another thing that helps is `mysqladmin flush-hosts` from the command line.

Where should I look? What should I do?...

Comment: Do you see any relevant errors in your error log ?

Comment: Nope, I checked windows events, mysql log and php log. I see myself restarting the server, but no 'refused connection' or such message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html

mysql> show variables;

take a look variable max_connect_errors, you can try increase it.

Comment: I see it is at 10; I'm increasing it. However, the WP is on the same server and I can connect locally without a problem as root or aas the WP user. Where will I see an error that relates to this? I looked att the logs but saw nothing like in the article you linked to.

Comment: it's should be on your webserver/php log, but if cannot found, cmiiw wordpress has debug setting (http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) you may enabled it and see what's the real problem.

Comment: I found the error. I see in my other servers that the max_connected_errors is 64 so I'll try to increase it, but I would like to do it through a configuration change... I only saw it altered by command-line execution of mysql. I didn't find it at my.ini. Any idea?

Comment: you just add the option on your my.ini under [mysqld] section, please refers to http://www.linuxweblog.com/tune-my.cnf